# Rails 5.0.0beta3 Action Cable - Messages only send in browser after I send one via Chrome Console?

Tags: actioncable

It's a really strange glitch. My website just isn't letting me send messages when the page is first loaded, messege sending and reciving is working perfectly though if I create a message through the Chrome browser console via App.room.speak("Hello")

Below is the .coffee. It's C&P'd from a tutorial and the tutorial have no problems so I'm wondering why this is happening.

```
App.room = App.cable.subscriptions.create "RoomChannel",
  connected: ->
    # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server


  disconnected: ->
    # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

  received: (data) ->
    $('#messages').append('<br>'+data['message'])

  speak: (message) ->
    @perform 'speak', message: message

    $(document).on 'keypress', (event) ->
      if event.keyCode is 13# return = send
        App.room.speak event.target.value
        event.target.value = ''
        event.preventDefault()
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby "2.3.0"

gem 'rails',        '5.0.0.beta3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier'  
gem 'faker'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'  
gem 'jbuilder'
gem 'puma', '3.4.0'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
gem 'execjs' 
gem 'actioncable', '~> 5.0.0.beta3'
gem 'sdoc', group: :doc

# Security
gem 'bcrypt'             

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
#  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'spring'     
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

And finally my application.html.erb file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(@title) %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= action_cable_meta_tag %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Body -->
<body>

  <!-- Navbar -->
  <%= render 'layouts/navbar' %>

  <!-- Flash -->
  <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
    <div class="slideanim2 fadeout alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
  <% end %>

  <!-- Main Container -->
  <% if !@container_mode.nil? && @container_mode == "FLUID" %>
    <div class = "container-fluid">
  <% else %> 
    <div class = "container">
  <% end %>

  <!-- Render main page content -->
  <%= yield %>

  <!-- Render Debug -->
  <% # debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
  </div>
</body>

<!-- Navbar -->
<%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
</html>


<!-- JQUERY STUFF -->
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

  setTimeout(function(){ $('.fadeout').fadeTo(1000, 0) }, 4000);

  $(".slideanim2").each(function(){
    var pos = $(this).offset().top;

    $(this).addClass("slide");
  });

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".slideanim").each(function(){
      var pos = $(this).offset().top;

      var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (pos < winTop + 600) {
          $(this).addClass("slide");
        }
    });
  });
})
</script>
```

Please help!

Comment: I should add! I have working messages once the console has been opened and a message sent via App.room.speak("Hello")

For some reason once I've done the console command you can type and press enter to send messages which is the desired behavior. I just don't understand why I need to open the console first and create a message via the console to get it working!

Comment: Okay so I've isolated the problem down a bit further, in my coffee file I have a line: App.room.speak("")

This is sending a blank message and calling speak, I'm still not sure why speak needs to be called first in order for the chat to work.